# I think deriving $E_f=\gamma^2E_i$ of the inverse Compton scattering is unreasonable

Tags: special-relativity, scattering

https://casper.astro.berkeley.edu/astrobaki/index.php/Inverse_Compton_Scattering

I have two questions on the above site's table of contents 1.1.

$\space$

1. Can $\theta_i\approx\theta'_f\approx\pi/2$ be aussmed?

Suppose that I observe inverse Compton scattering photon coming in line of my sight from several AGNs jets emitting different directions each other.

Then, there are several incident and scattering angle.

$\space$

2. How about using $E'_i = \frac{E_i}{\gamma(1+\beta\cos\theta'_i)}$ or $E'_f=E_f\gamma(1-\beta\cos\theta_f)$

As I know, those also can be used with changing the angle's reference frame.

For example, let's using $E'_i = \frac{E_i}{\gamma(1+\beta\cos\theta'_i)}$ and $E'_f = \frac{E_f}{\gamma(1+\beta\cos\theta'_f)}$.

Then, I get $E_f=\frac{1+\beta\cos\theta'_f}{1+\beta\cos\theta'_i}E_i$ and the factor $\frac{1+\beta\cos\theta'_f}{1+\beta\cos\theta'_i}$ does not seem to be $\gamma^2.$